# Como guardar array en un solo campo en msql

Tags: php, laravel, array, mariadb

tengo un problema tengo 3 tablas en las cuales en las dos primeras los datos se guardan correctamente, pero en la ultima tabla asignatura solo se guarda el valor de asignatura1 y codigoasignatura1 por cada iteracion del ciclo for, creo que el problema esta en la forma del como debo guardar los indices del array en un unico campo de la tabla. Agradezco su ayuda

[image: Imagen modo diseñador de mi base de datos]

### **Codigo de mi controlador**

```
 $pensum = new Pensum ();
    $pensum  ->carrera = $request ->carrera;
    $pensum  ->regimen = $request ->regimen;
    $pensum  ->vigencia = $request ->vigencia;
    $pensum ->numerosemestres = $request ->numerosemestres;
    $pensum -> save();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->asignatura1) ; $i++) {
    $semestre = array();
    
    $semestre= new Semestre ();
    $semestre->semestre = $request->numerodesemestre[$i];
    $pensum ->semestre()->save($semestre);
    
    
    $asignatura= new Asignatura ();
    
    $asignatura->nombreasignatura= $request->asignatura1[$i];
    $asignatura->codigoasignatura = $request->codigoasignatura1[$i];
    
    $asignatura->nombreasignatura= $request->asignatura2[$i];
    $asignatura->codigoasignatura = $request->codigoasignatura2[$i];
    
    $asignatura->nombreasignatura= $request->asignatura3[$i];
    $asignatura->codigoasignatura = $request->codigoasignatura3[$i];
    
    $semestre->asignatura()->save($asignatura);
    
    }
```

**He logrado la solucion** reemplanteando mi ciclo for ahora me guarda todos los datos de asignatura en solo dos campos de tabla asignatura, independiente de cantidad de semestres. Gracias por su ayuda

if   ( $request ->estado == 3) {

```
$pensum = new Pensum ();
$pensum  ->carrera = $request ->carrera;
$pensum  ->regimen = $request ->regimen;
$pensum  ->vigencia = $request ->vigencia;
$pensum ->numerosemestres = $request ->numerosemestres;
$pensum -> save();




for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->numerodesemestre) ; $i++) {


$semestre= new Semestre ();
$semestre->semestre = $request->numerodesemestre[$i];
$pensum ->semestre()->save($semestre);





 $registro = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura1[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura1[$i], ]
);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($registro);

 $registro = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura2[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura2[$i], ]);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($registro);


$registro = Asignatura::create([ 'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura3[$i], 'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura3[$i], ]);
$semestre->asignatura()->save($registro);



}
```

Comment: Lo interesante sería ver la consulta que usas para traer los datos. Hay posibilidad de traerlos en una sola columna y luego hacer un split de dicha columna y listo.

Comment: Jose para actualizar tu pregunta o agregar avances usa la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/113533/edit) , es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sito! Lee esta guía para realizar correctamente una respuesta [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

La solucion es la siguiente. Lo primero debes codificar el array a formato JSON.

```
$array = array( array('Elemento1' => '500', 'Elemento2'=> '50', 'Elemento3' => '0'));

$array_json = json_encode($array);

$consulta = $con -> query ("INSERT INTO tabla campo_array VALUES ('$array_json') WHERE id=1");
```

Una vez codificaste e insertaste el elemento JSON en tu BD lo observaras asi.

> [{"Elemento1":"500","Elemento1":"50"}]

Para decodificarlo seria Asi:

```
$arrayBD = json_decode($array ,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Asignatura::create([
   'nombreasignatura' => $request->asignatura2[$i],
   'codigoasignatura' => $request->codigoasignatura2[$i],
]);

Deja esto en el for para que cada vuelta guarde un objecto diferente.